# WordPress Ajax Filter

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

I am trying to get the **AJAX** filter to work in **Wordpress** but I keep getting an error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: reports is not defined filter.js?ver=1.0:5**

This is the plugin that I use to enqueue the script and localize it:

## ajax-filter.php

```
 function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reports', plugins_url( '/js/filter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

  wp_localize_script( 'reports', 'filters',
          array(
              'ajax_filter' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
  ));

 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
```

And this is the .js file that it enqueues

## filter.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").on( "change", function() {
        console.log($('input[name="filter[]"]:checked').serialize());
        jQuery.ajax({
        url : reports.ajax_filter,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'filter_reports',
            filter : options
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
});
});
```

This is the page where the filtering has to be done.

**page-home.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home Page */

get_header(); ?>

<header class="entry-header">
    <?php get_the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="ewf-row">
            <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
                <h1>
                Welcome <?php global $current_user;
                  get_currentuserinfo();

                  echo $current_user->display_name . "\n"; echo '<small style="font-size:12px;">' . $current_user->user_email . "\n" . '</small>'
                        ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <p>

<br>
<br>
<strong id="desktop-only">1 Way to access your reports</strong>
<strong id="mobile-only">2 Ways to access your reports</strong>
            </p>

            <p>
                <div id="ebook-btn-info" class="ebook-buttons-info">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="ebook-download-info">View</div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Click this option if you want to download and view the report(s) as a regular PDF document.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="mobile-only">
                        <div class="ebook-download-info">EPUB</div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Use the EPUB option if you want to install the report in the iBook or Kiosk app on your tablet or smartphone.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
            <div class="devider"></div>
        </br>

    <!--
<div id="ebooks-category">
    <div class="ebooks-category-title">Categories: </div>
    <a class="ebooks-active">EPIC</a>   <a href="http://epic.trmoncology.com/ebooks/#ebook-btn-info">EPIC - CC</a>

</div>

-->





<?php
 $disease = get_terms( array('disease') );
 $report    = get_terms( array('type')      );

?>

<div style="width:100%; float:left;"><strong>Reports currently available to you</strong></div>
<div class="devider"></div>

<div id="epic-filter">


    <h3>Disease Type</h3>
    <form name="disease" id="filter-disease">

        <?php
        foreach ($disease as $value) {
            echo '<div class="filter '.$value->slug.'">';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" data-filter=".'. $value->slug .'" class="'. $value->term_id .'" value="'. $value->term_id .'" name="filter[]" ><div class="filter-title">'. $value->name .'</div><span class="filter-count">'. $value->count .'</span>';
            echo '</div>';
            // echo $value->name;
        }
        ?>
    </form>

</div>




<!--Loop EPIC-->

<div id="ebook-wrapper">




<?php
$uid = get_current_user_id();

            //$user_cats = get_user_meta( $uid, 'categories', false );  // this should return the values as array

            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

            $customer_account  = get_field('customer_account', 'user_'.$uid );

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'ebooks',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'customer',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $customer_account,
                    )
                ),
            );


            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();

                $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'disease');
                foreach($terms as $term){
                ?>


            <!--Ebook Container-->

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('ebook-container'); ?> <?php echo 'data-cat="'. $term->slug .'"' ?>>

                <!-- <div class="ebook-date"><--?php the_time('M j') ?></div> -->
                        <!-- <a href="<--?php echo get_post_permalink ( $post->ID ); ?>"></a> -->

                        <!--Image-->
                        <div class="ebook-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo the_field('e-image'); ?>"> <!--This will get the featured Image attached -->
                        </div>

                        <div id="ebook-middle">
                        <!-- Title -->
                        <div class="ebook-title">
                            <?php echo the_field('e_detail_title'); ?>
                        </div>

                </div>



                <!--Content-->
                <div class="ebook-content">
                    <?php echo the_field('e-detail-intro') ?>
                </div>

            <!--Details-->
            <div id="ebook-details">
            <div class="e-detail ebook-details-chair"><strong>Chair: </strong><?php echo the_field('e-detail-chair'); ?></div>
            <div class="e-detail ebook-details-date"><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo the_field('e-detail-date'); ?></div>
            <div class="e-detail ebook-details-location"><strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo the_field('e-detail-location'); ?></div>
            </div>



                <div class="ebook-buttons">
                    <a href="<?php echo the_field('e-down-view'); ?>"><div class="ebook-download">View</div></a>
                    <a id="mobile-only" href="<?php echo the_field('e-pub'); ?>" download><div class="ebook-download">EPUB</div></a>
                </div>


                <!-- <?php
                if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
                     echo the_taxonomies( 'before=<ul>&after=</ul>' );
                } else {
                     echo "";
                }
                  ?> -->


            </div>

            <?php }} ?>

            <?php
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">No Ebooks available.</div>';
        }
        ?>
</div>
<!--Loop EPIC - END-->

        <!-- <ul class="pagination pull-right">
            <li class="pagination-prev"><--?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous Ebook List' ); ?></li>
                        <li class="pagination-next"><--?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next Ebook List', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></li>
                        <li class="pagination-viewall"><a href="http://local.ebooks.com/ebooks/">View All Ebooks</a></li>
        </ul> -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<script>


</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I really hope that you guys can help me.

I already looked up a solution but I cannot find anything that is related to my code.

Answer (score 1):

In the way you are using `wp_localize_script()`, the object's name is `filters`, not `reports`; so, in filter.js you should use `filters.ajax_filter`. Also, you should define the variable `options` before use it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").on( "change", function() {
        console.log($('input[name="filter[]"]:checked').serialize());
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : filters.ajax_filter,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'filter_reports',
                // You should define options var before use it
                // filter : options
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
  });
});
```

I suggest you to use more explicit names for the variables; choose names that explain themselves; of course that is just a opinion. For example:

```
// Use the name of the script as handle parameter
wp_enqueue_script( 'filter', plugins_url( '/js/filter.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

// Use a name for the object which explain that it is data for filter script
wp_localize_script( 'filter', 'filter_data',
          array(
              // Use a nanme that explain what the property contains
              'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
          )
);
```

Then, in filter.js you must use `filter_data.ajax_url`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").on( "change", function() {
        console.log($('input[name="filter[]"]:checked').serialize());
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : filter_data.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'filter_reports',
                // You should define options var before use it
                // filter : options
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: now i am gettting this: **Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined**

Comment: That is because this part of the code `filter : options`. Note that `options` is not defined anywhere in your code and that is what the error message says. What it should be? Can you explain it? There is not reference to `options` in your question nor in your code, so I can not know what it should be.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In your code, you have a reference to a variable named `options` but you have not defined that variable before you try to use it; that is why you get the reference error message, and the message explains itself the problem: "options is not defined". It is simple, you have to define a variable before use it. I don't know how to explain it better. If you don't understand this, try to search about "Defining variables in JavaScript", you will find a lot of information. If you have questions about JavaScript, StackOverflow is a good place to get help.